# Loading images from a folder in .net MAUI

Tags: android, maui

I am trying to display images from a folder like this:

```
 // Path to the folder containing photos
 string folderPath = "";

 // Get all the image file paths from the folder
 string[] imagePaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.png");

 // Create a stack layout to hold the photo squares
 StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();

 // Iterate through each image path
 foreach (string imagePath in imagePaths)
 {
     // Create an image view with the current photo
     Image photoImage = new Image
     {
         Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imagePath),
         Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill // Adjust aspect ratio of the image
     };

     // Create a square container for the photo
     Frame photoFrame = new Frame
     {
         CornerRadius = 10, // Optional: Round the corners of the frame
         Padding = 5,
         BackgroundColor = Colors.LightGray, // Optional: Set background color
         Content = photoImage,
         Margin = new Thickness(10) // Optional: Add margin between squares
     };

     // Add the photo square to the stack layout
     stackLayout.Children.Add(photoFrame);
 }
```

My objective is to have lots of images in a folder that need to be loaded in a page of a mobile app.
The problem is that while I know the correct path to the images when executing in windows, from an android phone I can't find the images in the application folder in /data.

Knowing that the path needed by `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.png");` is an absolute path, so I thought about putting all the images in a known folder, but i have no idea on how to do that and it may be a substantial amount of images.

I am new to MAUI and I have never worked with applications before, and I know that it probably is an extremely easy fix, but I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-a-local-image

Comment: Are you trying g to load images from the system photo gallery?

Comment: if not, where are these images coming from?  Are they deployed with the app, or do you download them at run time, or something else?

Comment: @Jason The images should come with the app. The best for what i need is if the images were stored in some folder inside the phone that I know the location of.

Comment: So they are embedded resources?  Please be **specific** about how they are being packaged with the app

Comment: I am new so I don't really know the specific terms. Reading online embed resources seem to be transformed into binary on install which is not how I'd like it. What I mean is that when installing the app on a phone, it automatically takes all the images and puts them in a folder. This is also because a feature could be the user adding his own photos but that's not really important now. The problem is that firstly I don't know how I'd do that, and secondly, for what I learned, the file structure could be different depending on brand.

Comment: In the last phrase I mean that a folder on my Samsung phone may not have the same path on a pixel phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [File Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) to select the file from the desired location.

On Android, you cannot transfer all images to a folder directly. However, you can access all images from the system.

Here is the code you can refer to:

```
public async Task<FileResult> PickAndShow(PickOptions options)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.FileName.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                result.FileName.EndsWith("png", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                using var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();
                var image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // The user canceled or something went wrong
    }

    return null;
}
```